# Generating QR codes using steeve:jquery-qrcode

Tags: jquery, meteor, package, qr-code

I am working on a meteor project where I want to assign each user a qr code.
I've done some research and have found out that the `steeve:jquery-qrcode` (found here: https://atmospherejs.com/steeve/jquery-qrcode) is a way of doing this.

Unfortunately I can't find any information on how to use this package.  Am I missing something?  Because the ReadMe file doesn't show much on the use of this package.

Otherwise is there a better package to use to generate qr codes in meteor projects?

Comment: A QR code is just a display medium for a string, much like a bar code font, so when you say "assign each user a qr code", do you mean "display users' name/id as a QR code"? If so, then you could generate the image server-side or client-side. IMHO, client-side is way simpler. The [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/jquery-qrcode) is about 14k.

Comment: I mean basically give each user a qr that redirects to their url which is www.example.com/@username

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this package just import the original jquery-qrcode. 
You can find the instructions here: https://github.com/jeromeetienne/jquery-qrcode.

```
// basic usage:
$('selector').qrcode({text: 'some string'});
```

If you have to generate the qrcode without using a reactive data source you can call the code on Template.YourTemplate.onRendered()

```
Template.YourTemplate.onRendered(function () {
  $('selector').qrcode({text: 'some string'});
});
```

but if you have to dynamically change the qrcode you could do something like this:

```
<template name="hello">
  <div class="testqrcode" data-qrcode="{{someReactiveData}}"></div>
</template>

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  var counter = new ReactiveVar(0);

  Meteor.setInterval(function () {
    counter.set(counter.get() + 10);
  }, 300);

  Template.hello.helpers({
    someReactiveData: function () {
      Tracker.afterFlush(function () {
        $('.testqrcode').each(function (i, e) {
          $(e)
            .empty()
            .qrcode({text: $(e).attr('data-qrcode')});
        });
      });
      return Meteor.absoluteUrl() + counter.get();
    }
  });
}
```

[DEMO of reactive example here](http://testqrcode.meteor.com/)

Comment: Note: Small error in the onRendered code, a } is missing at the end :)

Comment: @WalterB nice catch! Corrected!